# How can we let paths in Riemannian manifold flow towards being a geodesic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a Riemannian m-Manifold with metric tensor $g$. Let $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ be some sufficiently regular (lets say piecewise differeniable) path in M.
Is there some canonical way to let $\gamma$ "flow" (keeping $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ fixed) into a geodesic between $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$? If so how much does such a flow depend on the actual parametrisation of $\gamma$?

My idea would be to use the energy functional
$$E(\gamma)=\int_0^1g_{\gamma'(t)}(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))dt$$ and its functional derivative
$\frac{\partial E}{\partial\gamma}$. As the geodesics are exactly the critical points of $E$ I would hope to find a function
$$\Psi(r,t):[0,R]\times[0,1]\rightarrow M$$
such that for any $0<r\leq R$
$$\frac{\partial\Psi(r,t)}{\partial r} = -\frac{\partial E}{\partial\gamma}(\Psi(r,\cdot))(t).$$
However, I am not very firm in the theory of PDE, so I am not sure whether i can assume existence of $\Psi$, in particular if $\gamma$ is only piesewice differentiable.
Also, from this approach it seems very unclear to me how a reparametrisation of $\gamma$ would influence the resulting geodesic and how we can keep $\gamma(0), \gamma(1)$ fixed.

Comment: In a Riemannian surface, at least, the keyword is [curvature flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_curvature_flow).

Comment: Your flow is called the harmonic map heat flow.

Comment: Similar post in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134930/geodesics-and-harmonic-map-heat-flow)